# Check connection between two Queue managers

Tags: c#, ibm-mq, xms

I have an application that communicate with local IBM MQ Queue Manager that
is also connected with a remote Queue Manager.

Is there an event in the IBM c# API that can notify me when the connection between the local and the remote queue manager fell?

If there isn't what is the best way to get it ?

Comment: just browse the `Object Browser` in VS. and search for the events

Answer (score 0):

That is why you implement an MQ monitoring solution rather than put monitoring code in each application.